# django 2.2.3-Django 404 error ('Page not found') after runserver

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.2

My project is named 'tweetme', and when I runserver I get this error.

```
    Using the URLconf defined in tweetme.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^admin/
    ^static/(?P<path>.*)$

    The empty path didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += (static(settings.STATIC_URL,                 
document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT))
```

I expect to shows: the install worked successfully! Congratulation

but its shows me: Page not found at/

Comment: What is confusing about this error? You indeed haven't defined a URL pattern for `/`. It doesn't show you the congratulations page because you *have* defined one pattern, for /admin.

Comment: thnx for the editting , but how can i fix it

Answer (score 0):

You have defined only two url patterns in your config. So only those will successfully work as expected. For url / to work correctly, you will have to add additional url pattern as mentioned on Django documentation using " " or "/" in relative url

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs